# What is the decimal format used in ME3 coalesced files?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mods

I was messing in the biogames, and weapons file but what is the number system used? Never seen decimal points in hex before.

Any help would be amazing, I'm kinda just editing blind.

Comment: I don't have the game, so I can't say anything about what they're doing, but there's nothing *inherently* wrong with having fractional parts in a hexadecimal number. It's not seen all that often, but it's entirely well-defined how such a number should be interpreted - it's the same principle as decimal fractional parts, only with 16 as the base instead of 10.

Comment: Where exactly is this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways fractions could be implemented - as a fixed-point representation, in which case several of the least significant bits would store the fractional part or much more likely as IEEE-754 single- or double-precision floating point numbers. Wikipedia describes IEEE-754 floats in more detail than I could hope to give.

Comment: Sorry about the delay went on vacation its under coalesced/biogame

Comment: sorry about the delay went on vacation, so here is the example. adrenaline rush does a time dilation. which at base is 30% the base listed in the coalesced/biogames is basevalue=0.0f.